# Intellij, Update from Subversion, but push into GitHub

Tags: github, svn

I use Intellij to work on my project.

I update my project from Subversion but then I want to push all changes into my repository at GitHub.

The problem I'm facing is that when I update files from Subversion, the changes are not recorded as Local Changes, therefore I cannot commit them and then push into GitHub repository.

In other words, whatever update I get from Subversion, I want it to be pushed into the repository at GitHub.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate svn and github, or migrate from svn to git?

Comment: Integrate. I update my project from Subversion, that's where my developer prefers to keep the project. After his update and my local changes, I want to commit and push the updates into my repository at GitHub.